# How to insert a JFreeChart to a JPanel in a JFrame with null layout?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I need to insert a JFreeChart when a JFrame's layout is null.
Could someone help me?
I got a code from the internet, and did some modifications to set a null layout ('couse the original code uses border layout) and it is not working.

The code bellow is not working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BarChart();
}

public BarChart() {
    dataset.addValue(1.0, fiat, speed);
    dataset.addValue(3.0, fiat, userrating);
    dataset.addValue(5.0, fiat, millage);
    dataset.addValue(5.0, fiat, safety);

    dataset.addValue(5.0, audi, speed);
    dataset.addValue(6.0, audi, userrating);
    dataset.addValue(10.0, audi, millage);
    dataset.addValue(4.0, audi, safety);

    dataset.addValue(4.0, ford, speed);
    dataset.addValue(2.0, ford, userrating);
    dataset.addValue(3.0, ford, millage);
    dataset.addValue(6.0, ford, safety);

    JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("CAR USAGE STATIStICS",
        "Category", "Score", dataset,   PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    myChart = new ChartPanel(barChart);

    jPanel1.setLayout(null);
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    jPanel1.add(myChart,null);

    this.add(jPanel1);
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public ChartPanel getMyChart() {
    return myChart;
}

public void setMyChart(ChartPanel myChart) {
    this.myChart = myChart;
}
```

Comment: The short and long answer would be, don't use null layouts

Answer (score 1):

Your chart doesn't appear because you've set the layout of the JPanel to null. Without a layout the JPanel isn't able to manage the children and paint them based on their preferred sizes, which is why you see nothing when you run your code

By removing this line:

```
jPanel1.setLayout(null);
```

The JPanel will default to [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)

 (You can read more at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Which will display the following:

[image]

---

If you must have the layout as null, please read this post for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

But i would recommend using any of the layout managers available instead:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html